# I can't draw data from smart contract to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, smartcontracts

This is the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')

Here is the function that I'm using for drawing data from smart contract (and I call this function like getCandidate(1)):

```
async function getCandidate(cad){
    await myContract.methods.adaylar(cad);{
        var result;
        console.log("result : ", result);
        document.getElementById("cad" + cad).innerHTML = result[1];
        document.getElementById("cad"+cad+'count').innerHTML = result[2].toNumber();
        
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `adaylar()` function

- returns an array or a struct with at least 3 items (so that you don't run into "out of bounds" error while accessing `result[2]`)
- and that it's a `view` or `pure` function in Solidity

there are two issues in your code:

The [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/) library requires you to explicitly state if you want to make a (read-only) `call()` or `send()` a (read-write) transaction. Based on the assumption above, you'll want to make a call:

```
await myContract.methods.adaylar(cad).call();
```

This retrieves the returned value but doesn't store it anywhere in the JS code. So you'll need to store it in the `result` variable in order to access it:

```
var result = await myContract.methods.adaylar(cad);
console.log("result : ", result);
document.getElementById("cad" + cad).innerHTML = result[1];
document.getElementById("cad"+cad+'count').innerHTML = result[2].toNumber();
```